# Creating a .vim directory

Tags: vim, vimrc

I just installed Vim again and noticed there is no `.vim` directory in my `/home` directory. I have read that if I create `.vim` myself then this will override the values in `/etc/vim`. My questions:

1. Should the new directory that I create be `/home/.vim` or `/home/myusername/.vim`?
2. Should I delete `/etc/vim` and its content when the new `*/.vim` is created, or should I just leave it be?
3. Can I put `.vimrc` or even `vimrc` (without period) inside the new `.vim` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's always `/home/myusername/.something` when it's about personalisation. As long as your home dir is `/home/mysername`, of course. I'm not sure however if this can be a directory or has to be a file. If it's not stated in `man vim`, there's always trial and error.
2. No, you don't need to delete `/etc/vim`. Personalisations in the home dir should take precedence over the general `/etc` settings. Btw, there can also be something like `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` too. Sometimes the general settings in `/etc/` are linked to `/usr/share/something`.
3. As noted in point 1, `vim`'s documentation should be consulted. Trial and error if no details can be found in there.

Comment: this is a good answer, but for #3, the .vimrc file should be in your home dir, not in the .vim dir.

Comment: @JacobMinshall ~/.vimrc or ~/.vim/vimrc both work.

Answer (score 1):

1. `$HOME/.vim`
2. No
3. `$HOME/.vim/vimrc` or `$HOME/.vimrc`

---

1. Personalization happens in your home directory, `$HOME`.  This is usually `/home/username` on Linux, or `/Users/username` on macOS, or `/usr/username` on some old-fashioned systems.
2. Personalization of user applications never ever requires you to delete files installed by a package, and rarely requires even *modification* to files under `/etc`. Unix is a multi-user operating system: If you started deleting files under `/etc` just because you had your own personal configuration in `$HOME`, then you would break things for other users of the system.
3. See `:help vimrc` in Vim.

Answer (score -1):

1: the directory should be in "/home/username/" and not in "/home"(can be .vim or .vim**rc** by the way the 'rc' stands from run command
2: you should leave it there .Take a simply backup otherwise
3: that won't affect much as the .vimrc is the ones running commands for several things (aesthetics, primarily)but better to leave it where it previously was.
Side note- if you have many vim installations then there might be multiple .vi directories. Happened once with me .I had vi tiny vim and gvim all together and yet nothing was conflicted . I just left things as they were

Comment: Are you sure that you’re answering the question?

Comment: @Scott Thanks .I was Not to the point . Just a rook